# Python search and character extarction

Tags: python, search

I am wanting to search and extract unique numbers from a txt files.

Every line contains a unique 10 digit number beginning with 33- (33XXXXXXXX). How do I print just the number so that i end up with a list of 33XXXXXXXX numbers that are in the file? (Python)

I want to have all the number in a list separated by an "OR" statement?
**They are located at [155-156]

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for line in open("list_phones.txt"):
...     print(line.strip('\n'))
... 
33- (33534545)
45- (73727479)
67- (53512368)


>>> import re
>>> AllWords = []
>>> for line in open("list_phones.txt"):
...     AllWords.append(re.search(r"\(([0-9]+)\)", line).group(1))
... 
>>> for word in AllWords:
...     print(word)
... 
33534545
73727479
53512368
```

Use join() to join all elements in list & separate by a string/char.

```
>>> ' OR '.join(AllWords)
'33534545 OR 73727479 OR 53512368'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice if you mark the response as answer.